# When TCP connections are opened?

Tags: tcp, package, network-protocols, netstat

I wanted to define which version of HTTP is used(in empiric way) by monitoring the number of TCP connections which are opened when the browser requiring some page. I've chosen the page with 2 pictuers and run

```
netstat -s | grep "active connections"
```

The result was 1613

Then I've opened this page http://c2.com/doc/pages.html and run this command again:
The result was 1637.

How is that possible if I closed all the web clients which may send TCP packets, there're only browser and bash opened. Why so many TCP connections were opened?

Comment: There is no way you can find out which http version is being used by counting connections. Just because keep-alive connections are supported doesn't need they are used. It depends on both the client and the server application if they will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jørgensen says, the active connection openings list *all* the connections opened since the  TCP/IP stack was initialized (in practice last boot), so the 24 connections is not *that many*.

The number is not 1, but 24 probably because the browser does not send the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header, so the browser opens a new TCP connection to get all the elements (such as images) needed to render the page.

To see the amount of currently *ESTABLISHED* connections, do either:

```
netstat -nat|grep ESTABLISHED|wc -l
```

or

```
netstat -s |grep "connections established"
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, because if you actually look at the result, it shows "active connection openings", i.e. it counts all connections made *since the booting of the machine*.